# kafka delete a topic using bootstrap server vs zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to know the different between these commands.

```
-- With bootstrap server
kafka-topics \
--bootstrap-server b-1.bhuvi-cluster-secure.jj9mhr.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-2.bhuvi-cluster-secure.jj9mhr.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:9098  \
--delete \
--topic debezium-my-topic  \
--command-config /etc/kafka/client.properties
```

```
-- With zookeeper
 kafka-topics \
--zookeeper z-3.bhuvi-cluster-secure.jj9mhr.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:2182,z-1.bhuvi-cluster-secure.jj9mhr.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:2181,z-2.bhuvi-cluster-secure.jj9mhr.c3.kafka.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:2181 \
--delete \
--topic debezium-my-topic
```

The reason behind this is, the Kafka ACL for delete topic is restricted. If I run the first command it's giving an error like `Topic authorization failed` which is correct(due to ACL) but the second command didn't check anything from ACL and deleted the topic directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `authorizer.class.name` configured on the brokers may only depend on Kafka, and doesn't use Zookeeper AdminClient to verify ACLs

CLI `--zookeeper` option is considered deprecated, and will be completely removed with KIP-500